# T-SQL dynamic row checking

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic

I am trying to run a check on a table where, for each row, I want to see whether the column has a a null in it and add a 1 like here:

```
SELECT 
  ((CASE WHEN col1 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  + (CASE WHEN col2 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  + (CASE WHEN col3 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  ...
  ...
  + (CASE WHEN col10 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS sum_of_nulls
FROM table
WHERE Customer=some_cust_id'
```

This method does what its supposed to in a static way but is it possible to dynamically build the columns based on the table as opposed to writing out each case statement.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I came up with

```
declare 
    @sql nvarchar(max),
    @columns nvarchar(max),
    @table nvarchar(128) = '<your table here>'

select 
    @columns = stuff((select '+case when ' + quotename(column_name) + ' is null then 1 else 0 end'
                      from information_schema.columns
                      where table_name = @table
                      order by ordinal_position
                      for xml path('')), 1, 1, ''),
    @sql = 'select sum_of_nulls = ' + @columns + ', *
            from dbo.' + quotename(@table)

exec sp_executesql @sql
```

You can slot in a `where` clause after the table name if you want also. Right now, it just returns for everything in the table.

Comment: That does the trick. wow, I have a long way to go in sql from that statement lol.

Comment: Glad it worked. Yeah, there's a lot going on there, but here's the basics. The columns exist in information_schema (as well as sys.columns, but I chose to use informatoin_schema here). The funky syntax with the `for xml` is a little trick to serialize data into a delimited string. In this case, delimited by plus signs at the start of each column. the `stuff()` function is just there to strip off the leading plus sign. And that's about it.

Comment: Why You do not leave the plus there?

Comment: @AntonínLejsek If you leave the leading plus there, it's an invalid statement. Basically I'm serializing each row as `+case when ...`. So you'll end up with, for example, `+<statement1>+<statement2>+...<StatementN>`. See the leading plus sign though? That's what I'm trying to get rid of. There's several ways you can make the string valid, this is just my favorite.

Comment: The statement with unary plus on the beginning is valid and that is the reason why I am asking.

Comment: Because that's the weirdest syntax someone would voluntarily leave in their code. Plus it builds a good habit for serializing things with other delimiters.